# How to add the new value and update the existing value in array of objects on button click in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I am inserting the object values in the array on button click, I want to update the value of those objects if objects are already present in the array on same button click. How can I do that ?
I am adding the values in the array using push function which is as follows:

```
$scope.demoarray = [];

$scope.demoarray.push({                     
                        sample key1: $scope.demovalue1,
                        sample key2: $scope.demovalue2     
                       });
```

Comment: `$scope.demoarray = {key:value}` to update value `$scope.demoarray[0].key = value` or `$scope.demoarray[0]["key"]= value` witch `[0]` is the index of array element

Comment: Your shared code isn't very helpful. Could you show more of your logic or add a fiddle?

Comment: I want to update the existing record (if present) and add the new if record is not present in the same array $scope.demoarray = []; In this scenario is it work ? and if I want to put it in the same function what will be my condition to update the record ? @MamdouhFreelancer

Comment: How do you want to see if a record exists? By a property `id` or something?

Comment: Actually I have tried with it but it's creating new array record every time. I have done something as follows: for(var i = 0; i<$scope.demoarray.length; i++){
           if($scope.demovalue1 === $scope.demoarray[i]["demovalue1"]){$scope.demoarray[i]["sample key2"] = $scope.sample key2; } }

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.demoarray = [];

    $scope.demoarray.push({                     
                            sample key1: $scope.demovalue1,
                            sample key2: $scope.demovalue2     
                           });

    if($scope.demoarray.length>0){
    //if there is elements of array
    //reset the array
    //$scope.demoarray = [];
    //or push
    //$scope.demoarray.push({...});
    //or update item by index
    //$scope.demoarray[1] = {"newKey","newValue"}
    }

    if($scope.demoarray[0]["sample key1"]){
    //if there is value of key exists in the first item of array
    //$scope.demoarray.push({...});
    //or
    //$scope.demoarray[0] = {};
    //or
    //delete $scope.demoarray[0]["sample key1"];
    //$scope.demoarray.splice(0,1);
    //$scope.demoarray[1]["sample key1"]//key of 2nd item
    //$scope.demoarray[2]["sample key1"]//key of 3nd
    }

    if($scope.demoarray[0]["sample key1"]=="specific"){
    //take any action
    }   
    //and you can loop over all items using for
   for(var i=0;i<$scope.demoarray.length;i++){
   //use any if statements above working with i as index
   for(var k in $scope.demoarray[i]){
   console.log(k +" : "+ $scope.demoarray[i][k]);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code considering that if any key matched edit that record  -

```
$scope.demoarray = [];
var index1=-1;
var index2=-1;
var recordToBeAdded:{
             key1: $scope.demovalue1,
             key2: $scope.demovalue2};
  if($scope.demoarray.lenght>0){
   index1 = $scope.demoarray.findIndex(x=>x.key1===recordToBeAdded.key1) //find index of 1st key
   index2 = $scope.demoarray.findIndex(x=>x.key1===recordToBeAdded.key2) // find index of 2nd key
 }

  if(index1==-1 && index2==-1) // add if record is new
    {
        $scope.demoarray.push(recordToBeAdded);
     }                     
  else if(index1!==-1) // add edit same record if found 1st key matched
 {
   $scope.demoarray[index1] = recordToBeAdded
 }
 else{ // edit record if 2nd key matched
     $scope.demoarray[index2] = recordToBeAdded
    }
```